# How to custom field customer create api on Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to add **"Age"** field into customer When I Create customer

**Example**: Create Customer API

**Method**: POST URL: rest/V1/customers

```
{
  "customer": {
    "email": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "gender": 0,
    "storeId": 0,
    "taxvat": "string",
    "websiteId": 0,
    "customAttributes": [
    ]
  },
  "password": "string",
  "redirectUrl": "string"
}
```

Where do I fix it file

Comment: what did you tired, please mention it please.

Comment: Default Api Create Customer Don't have fied "Age" I want add this fied to api

Where do I fix it file